# Disable ApiVersioning for OData controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, versioning

is there any way to disable ApiVersioning only for OData controllers?

I have an application in which there are REST controllers and OData controllers. The problem occurs when I add AddApiVersioning. REST Controllers work as they should. OData controllers returns HTTP ERROR 404.

If I remove AddApiVersioning then OData controllers work properly.

The application is running on ASP.NET Core 3.1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ...
        serviceCollection.AddOData();           

        serviceCollection.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });
        ...
    }        

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            ...
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "/odata", ODataConfiguration.GetEdmModel());
            ...
        });
        ...
    }
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: am facing the exact situation.